# Highcharts export server not serving two parallel requests

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts nodejs export server, which is used by a microservice to generate chart images. The export server works fine as long it has sequential requests, in one case where i have multiple cron jobs requesting the export server per minute for the image and if 2 cron jobs request at them same timethe second request is not served.

Here is my chart exporter code

```
ChartsService.prototype.exportChartToPNG = function (data, name) {   
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    try {
        let exportSettings = this.exportChart(data, name);

        let fileExtension;

        if(data.filetype){
            fileExtension = data.filetype
        }
        else{
            fileExtension = 'png'
        }

        this.initPool();
        exporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
            if (res) {
                let FilePath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'chartimages', name + '.' + fileExtension);

                if (res.filename) { // for svg and pdf
                    fs.rename(res.filename, FilePath, function (err) {
                        deferred.resolve(FilePath);
                    });
                }

                if (res.data) { // for other fileformats
                    fs.writeFile(FilePath, res.data, 'base64', function (err) {
                        deferred.resolve(FilePath);
                    });
                }                
            } else {
                console.log("Promise rejected : " + JSON.stringify(err) + " ExportSettings : " +
                JSON.stringify(exportSettings));
                deferred.reject();
            }

        });    
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, could you provide us with your cron jobs configuration (crontab)? How many and in what order specific jobs are called? Have you tried to do cron jobs one after another? Does the exporting process for both result in a success?

In case of a failed exporting process, do you receive any error messages? Provide us with some logs.

Also, please provide us with an adjusted code that can be run as a separate node module that results in a successfully exported chart. This way we can test it on our side.

As for now, until you provide us with all necessary information, you can try to set a higher number of worker processes when you init the pool and see if that helps (https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#worker-count--work-limit).

Also, have you considered simply starting a server once and then sending requests to it?

Comment: Thanks pawel! I have 2 crons which send requests to the export server per minute. The corns are activated at the same time and both the requests arrive at the same time to the export server. When i try with one job after another, it works perfectly. In case of parallel requests we receive following error msg "Promise rejected : 0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data" even if input data is correct. Please find our export server code which runs as a separate node module and the sample input data with export settings on the following URL.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wJaeCeZwEdnDPv0a7CkO4nNtnKLDwwuG?usp=sharing